# Should I nest data in Redux or not and use if in a loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to React, but not to development. I'm currently working on my first independent project after doing training.

I'm creating a little app where the user can create any kind of list and list items within it. I have the following Lists and List Items:

List -> Kid Movies (ID: 1, Completion tag: Watched)
List Items (under Kid Movies):

- Cinderella (List Item ID: 1, List ID: 1, Last Completed DT:
  2021-03-22 10:00:00)
- Sleeping Beauty (List Item ID: 2, List ID: 1, Last Completed DT:
  2021-03-20 12:00:00)
- Finding Nemo (List Item ID: 4, List ID: 1, Last Completed DT:
  2021-03-18 10:30:00)

List -> Cleaning (ID: 2, Completion tag: Done)
List Items (under Cleaning):

- Vacuum (List Item ID: 3, List ID: 2, Last Completed DT: 2021-03-17
  10:30:00
- Mop (List Item ID: 5, List ID: 2, Last Completed DT: 2021-03-18
  12:30:00
- Bathroom (List Item ID: 6, List ID: 2, Last Completed DT: null

In the app, once they login, the home page shows them the Lists (Kid Movies and Cleaning) as button options.  On click of the List buttons, it shows them the List Items (Cinderella, Sleeping, Beauty, and Finding Nemo, etc). From the List Items page, there's also a button to Create List Item.  Previously, I had all of this working when it was just List Items and the action creator and reducer were both really simple.

**Here's my main question**: Is it better to keep all the data together in Redux and use an if statement in the component to determine if that record should be rendered based on the record's List ID **OR** nest the data by List ID in Redux (and if this is the superior approach, I need some help with Redux)?

I got the nested approach to load the List Items.  But then when I tried Creating new List Items, I couldn't get those to show up on the List Items page, because something in my Reducer is incorrect.

Here's the Action Creator:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_LIST_ITEMS:
        console.log('Now Reducing');
        console.log(action.payload);
        const listItems = _.mapKeys(action.payload, 'list_item_id');
        console.log(listItems);
        console.log(action.payload[0].list_id);
        ///return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(..._.mapKeys(action.payload, 'list_item_id'), 'list_id') }; //Not working
        //return { ...state, [action.payload[0].list_id]: listItems }; //works, but listItemList is breaking
        return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, 'list_item_id') }; //orignal
    case FETCH_LIST_ITEM:
        return { ...state, [action.payload.list_item_id]: action.payload };
    case CREATE_LIST_ITEM:
        console.log('Now Reducing CREATE');
        console.log(action.payload);
        //const thisItem = _.mapKeys(action.payload, 'list_item_id');
        //console.log(listItems);
        console.log(action.payload.list_id);
        const myData = { [(action.payload.list_item_id)] :  [(action.payload)] };
        //const myData[action.payload.list_item_id] = action.payload;
        console.log('myData');
        console.log(myData);
        //return { ...state, [action.payload.list_id]: myData };
//the new record doesn't show on the List Items page for the List
        return { ...state, [action.payload.list_id]: _.mapKeys(action.payload, 'list_item_id') };
        //return { ...state, [action.payload.list_item_id]: action.payload }; // original
```

Here's my mapStatetoProps in the component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { 
        listItems: Object.values(state.listItems),
        currentUserData: state.auth.userId,
        currentUserId: state.auth.userId.user_id,
        isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn,
        auth: state.auth
    };
};
```

[image: Nested Data Structure in Redux]
[image: Non-Nested Data Structure in Redux]

Comment: I recommend a flat approach.  `listItems` are one branch of state.  `lists` are another.  The `lists` would just store the `id` of the items.  You can use a selector function to get the actual objects for a given list.

Comment: Although you only *need* the relationship in one direction.  It looks like items know what list they belong to, so the list doesn't really need to know what items it contains because you could find them